# Mac Installer Wrong Download Progress

Tags: macos, installation, package, packagemaker

I'm facing a problem with Mac Installer.
I have a Distribution package that references other packages.
The referenced packages are downloaded during installation time (pkg-ref poiting to a http link).
The problem is that the download percentage is being multiplied by 100.
I tried changing the Distribution script inside the flat package to report a different package size, but it didn't work. It just changed the installation size estimation.
I also tried changing the PackageInfo of the remote package, but had no success.

Everything leads me to the idea that the problem is in the Apple Installer.app (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installer_(OS_X)), but I could not find any reported similar problem on the internet.

I'm using Packages (http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) to build my .pkg's

Comment: Any news? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in the Apple installer, see [the Installer-Dev list archives](http://lists.apple.com/archives/installer-dev/2013/Aug/msg00004.html). Please file a bug report with [Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com).